# swift 2.0 @available doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, ios9

I'm trying to run this code on iOS7 and it fail

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
class WatchConnection: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {

    class func sharedInstance() -> WatchConnection {
        struct WatchConnectionSingleton {
            static let instance = WatchConnection()
        }
        return WatchConnectionSingleton.instance
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activateSession()
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

But this works

```
import WatchKit
import WatchConnectivity

class WatchConnection: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {

    class func sharedInstance() -> WatchConnection {
        struct WatchConnectionSingleton {
            static let instance = WatchConnection()
        }
        return WatchConnectionSingleton.instance
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        guard #available(iOS 9.0, *) else { return }

        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activateSession()
        }
    }

    // use with invalidated session
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func getUserId(completion: ((String?) -> Void)?) {
```

Comment: Are you trying to run in iOS9 or iOS7?

Comment: In iOS7. In iOS9 works fine.

Comment: Can you post some error output? IIRC, the @available tags aren't available below iOS 8

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use `@available` in iOS 7.

You can use following to check version :

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] < 8.0) {
    //For iOS 7 or less
}
else{
    //Check for available 
}
```

Check the [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html)

Also check here it is described in this [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking).

Swift 2.1 [Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html) there is syntax like `#available`. Please check prerelease [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html)

---

And about the guard statement condition :

*A guard statement is used to transfer program control out of a scope if one or more conditions aren’t met.*

Comment: Are you sure? Can you post a link to apple doc?

Comment: @Arsen Updated answer with document.

Comment: Thanks. But `guard #available(iOS 9.0, *) else { return }` looks like working on ios7

Comment: attributes  are part of language specification, so it should work on every OS, which support the language. the standard libraries are linking with the application, so there is no reason, why not use available for app running on iOS7. For me it looks like a bug ... (if your deployment target is set to iOS7)